# SQL using trigger for constraint

Tags: sql, triggers, constraints

I am studying triggers and constraints.

And I got a question to use trigger (To be honest, I am not really sure how to use trigger..)

Let's say we have a Teachers table.

And this teacher table contains teacher_id , ssn , first_name , last_name , class_time

for example,

```
|teacher_id|ssn    | first_name | last_name | student_number| max_student
|1         |1234   | bob        | Smith     | 25            |25
|2         |1235   | kim        | Johnson   | 24            |21
|3         |1236   | kally      | Jones     | 23            |22
```

and

let's say the max number of student number will be 25.(max number of student will be defined by teacher, so it can be any number like 10, 22 , 25...)

and a student wants to add the bob's class. However, I want to make the trigger that rejecting to add the student.(because bob's class is already full..)

However, I am not really sure the way to create the trigger .. :( .. (this is the first time to study about  trigger.... )

Can anyone help to create the sample code to understand trigger part?

Comment: You'll have to add which database you're interested in, since triggers tend to be database specific.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! No need for messy `&nbsp;` orgies and `<br>` tags, really ....

Comment: This is a business rule, which I would have expected to be implemented in your application software rather than as a trigger or constraint in the database. Database constraints and triggers generally enforce referential integrity (that is, they keep data consistent internally) and although it may possibly be a backstop to ensure that classes don't go over 25, your app should really stop the attempt in the first place.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson: sounds to me they are interested in the `Academia` database. p.s. did you mean to ask what DBMS they are interested in? ;)

Comment: @onedaywhen Yeah, one should not comment before coffee :)

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I agree the rule should be enforced in every application that uses the database. I disagree that it is an either or consideration. The ideal is for both database and applications to use a common business rules repository; if that is not possible then it should be enforced in both places i.e. applications should refrain from writing bad data via validation and the database should prevent bad data from being committed via constraints. p.s. Excel is a commonly used application to work with databases (give them the privileges, they will come!): how do you enforce the rule in Excel?!

Comment: @onedaywhen: well if you're going to introduce other access routes which aren't mentioned in the question and may not form part of the design (db credentials need to be known), then things may need to be changed to match. Frankly I wouldn't grant privileges to use Excel to update data; but it's useful for analysis so `select` privileges are the most which should be granted. However, I would not agree that `26` is "bad data"; it contravenes a business rule, it doesn't render the database inconsistent.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: as I understand it, the `25` is the maximum number of students that can be enroled in Bob's class. When the 26th student is enroled in Bob's class then the data is inconsistent because the `teachers` table says the class size cannot exceed `25`.

Comment: @onedaywhen: No, that's not inconsistent, it means a business rule hasn't been followed. Inconsistent means that an update which should have affected something else has not done so.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: the definition you give for 'inconsistent' seems to me be different to the dictionary meaning and unintuitive. I wonder if you can provide a citation? Remember that a row in a database table is a predicate which is taken to be true. A row on one table represent that it is true that no more than 25 students can take Bob's class. A row in another table may say Ravi is the 26th enroled in Bob's class. Both cannot be true. How is that not 'inconsistent'?

Comment: @onedaywhen: I've found http://web.ing.puc.cl/~marenas/publications/tplp03.pdf which indicates that inconsistency means a violation of referential integrity rather than misapplication of a business rule which does not affect referential integrity. The paper deals with the mathematics of correcting such invalidated integrity.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: thanks for the link (good work :) Quote (first sentence of abstract): "A relational database is inconsistent if it does not satisfy a given set of integrity constraints" -- It is important to note that a *referential integrity constraint* is only one flavour of integrity constraint. They first say, "We
concentrate mainly on logic programs for binary integrity constraints." Then they say, "In section 6 we illustrate how to handle referential integrity constraints" -- if this paper was all about *referential integrity constraints* why do they only get around to them in section 6!

Comment: ...Rather, a more careful reading should reveal to you that an integrity constraint is a more general term than you seem to think. Examine example 1 (page 2) "When we ask about the tuples that are consistent wrt the FD, we should retrieve only (P.Jones, 3000) and (M.Stone, 7000), because those tuples should stay in any reasonable way in which we restore consistency." The example involves only one table and the constraint in question is a unique constraint. Hence this paper confirms that *inconsistent* applies to all flavours of constraint, not just the referential kind.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, I think this is a data rule and therefore should be enforced centrally. That is, there should be a database constraint (or equivalent) enforced by the DBMS that prevents all applications for writing bad data (rather than relying on the individual coders of each application to refrain from writing bad data).

Second, I think an `AFTER` trigger is appropriate (rather than an `INSTEAD OF` trigger).

Third, this can be enforced using foreign key and and row-level `CHECK` constraints.

For a constraint type trigger, the idea generally is to write a query to return bad data then in the trigger test that this result is empty.

You haven't posted many details of your tables so I will guess. I assume `student_number` is meant to be a tally of students; as it is it sounds like an identifier so I will change the name and assume the identifier for students is `student_id`:

```
WITH EnrolmentTallies
     AS
     (
      SELECT teacher_id, COUNT(*) AS students_tally
        FROM Enrolment
       GROUP 
          BY teacher_id      
     ) 
SELECT * 
  FROM Teachers AS T
       INNER JOIN EnrolmentTallies AS E
         ON T.teacher_id = E.teacher_id
            AND E.students_tally > T.students_tally;
```

In SQL Server, the trigger definition would look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER student_tally_too_high ON Enrolment
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF EXISTS (
           SELECT * 
             FROM Teachers AS T
                  INNER JOIN (
                              SELECT teacher_id, COUNT(*) AS students_tally
                                FROM Enrolment
                               GROUP 
                                  BY teacher_id      
                             ) AS E
                                  ON T.teacher_id = E.teacher_id
                                     AND E.students_tally > T.students_tally
          )
BEGIN
RAISERROR ('A teachers''s student tally is too high to accept new students.', 16, 1);
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
RETURN 
END;
```

There are some further considerations, however. Executing such a query after every `UPDATE` to the table may be very inefficient. You should use `UPDATE()` (or `COLUMNS_UPDATED` if you think column ordering can be relied upon) and/or the `deleted` and `inserted` conceptual tables to limit the scope of the query and when it is fire. You will also need to ensure that transactions are properly serialized to prevent concurrency problems. Although involved, it isn't terribly complex.

I highly recommend the book [Applied Mathematics for Database Professionals  By Lex de Haan, Toon Koppelaars](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-uYZcnEt4uQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=applied+mathematics+for+database+professionals&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rYJgT7S3BcG_0QX7ouidBw&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=trigger&f=false), chapter 11 (the code examples are Oracle but can be easily ported to SQL Server).

---

It may be possible to achieve the same without triggers. The idea is to make a superkey on `(teacher_id, students_tally)` to be referenced in the Enrolment, for which a sequence of unique student occurrences will be maintained with a test that the sequence will never exceed the maximum tally.

Here's some bare bones SQL DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE Students 
(
 student_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE (student_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Teachers 
(
 teacher_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
 students_tally INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (students_tally > 0), 
 UNIQUE (teacher_id), 
 UNIQUE (teacher_id, students_tally)
);

CREATE TABLE Enrolment
(
 teacher_id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 students_tally INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (students_tally > 0), 
 FOREIGN KEY (teacher_id, students_tally)
    REFERENCES Teachers (teacher_id, students_tally)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
 student_id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE 
    REFERENCES Students (student_id),
 student_teacher_sequence INTEGER NOT NULL
    CHECK (student_teacher_sequence BETWEEN 1 AND students_tally)
 UNIQUE (teacher_id, student_id), 
 UNIQUE (teacher_id, student_id, student_teacher_sequence)
);
```

Then add some 'help' stored procs/functions to maintain the sequence on update.

Comment: sorry , i forget to put max_student from the table. I am studying to create the TRIGGER which is able to check limit of enrollment when student want to enroll the classes. For example , if max_student == student_number then student can't add the class. Anyway , it really help me to understand TRIGGER. thanks :)